# Android: is better to do many activities, or 1 activity that changes on the fly?

Tags: android, android-layout

If I need to do 10 similar activities, is it better I do:

- 10 activities and 10 layout?
- 1 activity and 10 layout?
- 1 activity and change the UI with visibility gone/visible?

I need an answer for:

1. performance
2. formality

Comment: It'll probably be easier to code multiple activities, and you can get benefits from events such as OnResume().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use multiple activities, you will get the advantage of using the android activity stack mechanism. So if you want your users to be able to navigate with the back button, then it's the best bet.

Also, if your activities are very similar, then you can implement common code in an abstract class, and make your 10 activities extend this common class, thus sharing some code.

```
public abstract class CommonBehaviorActivity extends Activity {
    protected void buildCommonThings() {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(getTitle());
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image)).setDrawable(...);
        }

    abstract protected String getTitle();
}

public class MyActivity1 extends CommonBehaviorActivity {
    ...
    protected String getTitle() {
        return "Title 1";
        }
}
```

and so on...

**Edit :** Added some sample code to show how to share things that you want to see in every sub-activity. For example, if you have a list in each activity, then you can define a specific adapter in the sub-activities in a `getAdapter()` method, and bind your list to this adapter in the `CommonBehaviorActivity` as well as configure it (bind listeners, and so on...)

---

On the other side, if you want to have a very fast switch between your activities, and you don't need to be able to go "back" with the button, then visible/gone view is maybe better.

Comment: for activity is all clear.. but for layout? when i do the xml layout can i do a "title + icon part" layout that it is the same for each layout? i am understaning that this is the fragment things, right? (sorry for my english :( )

Comment: ok i found it.. there is the <include> to use other xml piece.. ty

Answer (score 1):

Making several activities will make your code more readable and easier to debug as you won't deal with excessive if and else conditions. There will be no performance overhead: Activities load fast and Android manages the backstack and free up memories by killing paused activities when needed (which won't be the case with a single one).

If your activities are similar, you can put features in separate classes and re-use them across activities. Idem for layouts, you can design them so you can re-use common parts.

Comment: how can i use common part? for example.. if each layout have same Title + image, how can i use this for each layout?

Comment: I modified my answer above with a sample code that shows how to share common behaviors in the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use fragments if you want to for display dynamic UI. You can change content in fragment dynamically or you can change the fragment itself. You can always keep certain fragment visible and others inactive. In this case you will only need one activity and multiple fragments.

It will depend how you want draw UI of your app.  Fragments examples are available is [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

Comment: it sound cool.. but i know fragment don't work in android 2.3, right?

Comment: No..Fragment work with Android 1.6 and later. You can use support library. See this post on the Android blog: [**Fragments For All**](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html)